Export a ggplot to jpeg with a larger text size, keeping the theme
I have an R project with several plots. I want to be able to visualise the plots in Rstudio with a regular font size, and export them with a larger font size in a jpeg file to have a high enough resolution. I want to write this in a generic function that I'll be able to reuse throughout my project. My issue: I can not find a way to do so while keeping the theme of my plot.
Reproducible code
library(ggplot2)

# Theme options set globally
theme_set(theme_minimal())
theme_update(
  text = element_text(family = "Sansation"),
  strip.text = element_text(colour = "black", face = "bold"),
  strip.background = element_rect(
    fill = "grey90",
    colour = "grey90",
    linewidth = 1
  ),
  panel.border = element_rect(
    colour = "grey90",
    fill = NA,
    linewidth = 1
  ),
  legend.position = "bottom",
  legend.title = element_text(hjust = .5),
  legend.box = "horizontal",
  plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
  plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
  plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
)

# Data simulation
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(n = 300), 
                 y = rnorm(n = 300),
                 group = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 100))

# Create an example plot
gg <- ggplot2::ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = group)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ group)
  # + possible theme options for specific plots

# Visualise the plot (with the default text size)
print(gg)

# Define the function to export the plot (with a bigger text size)
save_jpeg_plot <- function(gg, filename, width = 1800, height = 1000, pointsize = 20, base_size = 20) {
  jpeg(filename = filename, width = width, height = height, pointsize = pointsize)
  print(gg + theme_minimal(base_size = base_size))
  dev.off()
}
save_jpeg_plot(gg, <my_path>)

As you can see, this function removes the custom theme of my plot and replace it by theme_minimal.



My original plot
My exported plot









1st possibility
I would have loved to have a possibility to change the base_size outside of a predefined theme function (e.g. theme_minimal()). If this option is available, it would be great, but I couldn't find a way to do so.
2nd possibility
I think it may be possible to retrieve the plot theme given to the function, and do something like:
save_jpeg_plot <- function(gg, filename, width = 1800, height = 1000, pointsize = 20, base_size = 20) {
  gg_theme <- #something here to retrieve the theme options
  jpeg(filename = filename, width = width, height = height, pointsize = pointsize)
  print(gg +
          theme_minimal(base_size = base_size) +
          gg_theme
  )
  dev.off()
}

but it could be tricky as this would require not saving the text size in the original theme into the gg_theme  object.
Other possibilities?

Retrieve only the text size of text components of the theme and multiply them all by a factor?
Fix the text size for each of the text components of the theme? But I'm not a fan, because I could possibly want to custom the size of certain elements, and then the proportionnality between text sizes I chose would be messed up.


It's very possible I've missed a very simple solution here, so feel free to suggest other things!

Does ggsave give you what you want? You have a call to  theme_minimal in your export code that isn’t present in your visualisation code. That’s probably why you’re “losing” your theme. Try using theme instead.

ggsave combined with the scale parameter works relatively well. Thanks!
To answer on why I used theme_minimal, it's because unfortunately base_size is not an argument of theme, and I haven't figured out how to change the base_size in any other way that using a predefined theme.

You mention "high enough resolution". Have you tried the dpi= argument of ggsave(), instead of changing the sizes of the text and the output file?

I tend to make my own themes, and define all the text sizes as relative to the value for text = element_text(size = 16), like strip.text = element_text(size = rel(1.4)), then all I have to do is adjust the value for the  text = element_text() in the theme.

Helpful tutorial on resolution & text size in ggplot2: https://www.christophenicault.com/post/understand_size_dimension_ggplot2/.  You might also look at the camcorder package to help your workflow as you tweak font sizes: it makes it a faster iteration cycle by showing ggsave output directly in the Viewer window.
